# How we can interpret the behaviour of the residuals in a time series data?

Tags: time-series, econometrics, autocorrelation, residuals, gretl

Is there a potential presence of autocorrelation in the error term?[image]

Comment: 0. Welcome to CV. 1. Can you please add the autocorrelation function (ACF) and the partial ACF plot to your post?

Answer (score 0):

visually the time-series does not look very persistent. But who knows...
The simplest way to detect serial correlation is to compute the ACF and PACF by means of the gretl command `pergm`. For a reference see here:
http://gretl.sourceforge.net/gretl-help/cmdref.html#pergm

Also after having estimated a model, for instance by OLS using gretl `ols` command, you can easily conduct a statistical test on autocorrelation. Here is an example on how to run the Breusch-Godfrey test for autocorrelation up to order 8

```
open denmark.gdt
ols LRM 0 LRY IBO
modtest 8 --autocorr
```

For details on the `modtest` command see here: http://gretl.sourceforge.net/gretl-help/cmdref.html#modtest